# use two pipelines for python input file argument and stdin streaming

Tags: python, linux, bash, hadoop

Is there a one-liner approach to running the following python script in linux bash, without saving any temporary file (except /dev/std* ) ?
my python script test.py takes in a filename as an argument, but also sys.stdin as a streaming input.

```
#test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
fn=sys.argv[1]
checkofflist=[]
with open(fn,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        checkofflist.append(line)

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line in checkofflist:
        # do something to line
```

I would like to do something like

```
hadoop fs -cat inputfile.txt > /dev/stdout | cat streamingfile.txt | python test.py /dev/stdin
```

But of course this doesn't work since the middle cat corrupts the intended /dev/stdin content. Being able to do this is nice since then I don't need to save hdfs files locally every time I need to work with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
python test.py <( hadoop fs -cat inputfile.txt ) <streamingfile.txt
```

In bash, `<( ... )` is [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). The command inside the parentheses is run with its output connected to a fifo or equivalent, and the name of the fifo (or `/dev/fd/n` if bash is able to use an unnamed pipe) is substituted as an argument. The tool sees a filename, which it can just open and use normally. (`>(...)` is also available, with input connected to a fifo, in case you want a named streaming output.)

Comment: This would work, but feels backwards: it forces the actual file to be read via standard input, and the output stream from hadoop is forced into a file instead of using a pipe.

Comment: @chepner: I agree, but that's the nature of the python script in the OP. However, process substitution is pretty flexible; you could provide both arguments as named files, and use process substitution for whichever you wanted to stream.

Answer (score 0):

Without relying on `bash` process substitution, you might also try

```
hadoop fs -cat inputfile.txt | python test.py streamingfile.txt
```

This provides `streamingfile.txt` as a command-line argument for `test.py` to use as a file name to open, as well as providing the contents of `inputfile.txt` on standard input.